# How to rotate ImageVector’ pathData in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to implement similar animation like this, with **Jetpack Compose**

figure: https://dribbble.com/shots/4762799-Microinteraction-Exploration-002

[image: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/997655/screenshots/4762799/media/7bb1721ff6c539a6b34dddef4d7d713d.gif]

For the play icon’s transformation (*from a triangle to a rectangle*) , it not difficult to get it done by using path morphing animation.After reading some gist, I found that I can build an `ImageVector` by supplying the `pathData` , that's new to me~

While for ****the part on the right, the rotation of the cube object. Well, maybe I should call that a rolling-over or whatever,  because the cube changed its `pivot` after `-90` degrees.

I'm wondering that wether I can create  a `VectorGroup` for the cube’s `pathData`  and animate it by updating its group parameters.

> re: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector.Builder#addGroup

```kotlin
ImageVector.Builder(defaultWidth = 100.dp, defaultHeight = 100.dp, viewportWidth = 100, viewportHeight = 100)
        .addGroup(name = "CubeRotation", rotate = params.rotate, pivotX = params.pivotX, pivotY = params.pivotY,)
        .addPath(pathData = pathData, fill = SolidColor(Color.LightGray))
        .clearGroup()
        .build()
```

Here I trying to update the `pivotX`  halfway through the animation, so I divide it into two section:

```kotlin
// rotate -90 degrees twice with different pivot
val rotate = if (fraction <= 0.5f) {
    lerp(0f, -180f, fraction)
} else {
    lerp(0f, -180f, fraction - 0.5f)
}
// change the pivotX
val pivotX = if (fraction <= 0.5f) 52f else 30f
GroupParams(
    pivotX = pivotX,
    pivotY = 100f,
    rotate = rotate,
)
```

Frustratedly, after rotating by the first `-90` degrees, the transformation that this rotation performed will NOT persist,  -or- its transformation NOT being applied after the half time of the transition.

[image]

fraction: 0~0.5

[image]

fraction: 0.5~1

The code sample I've uploaded: [IndicatorDrawable.kt](https://github.com/80998062/DribbbleShowcase/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/sinyuk/compose/dribbbleshowcase/playbutton/IndicatorDrawable.kt)

Can I implement the rotate transformation by just updating the `pathData` ?

For me, the `VectorGroup`  in `ImageVector`  looks like creating `AnimatedVectorDrawable` in xml,  or maybe I should try some traditional way like `ObjectAnimationSet` in View system ?